# dynamic javascript element change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to change the user embedd link text by user selection.
The form has 2 textboxes, one for user input with onkeyup event 
and another is readonly textbox with a href html tag

When user starts typing inside the first textbox, the readonly input needs to be changed.

i tried diffrente ways but it didnt worked

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAlinkTitle" runat="server" Text="Register Now" onkeyup="func(this,<%=txtALink.ClientID%>)" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtALink" Text="<a href='http://google.com'>my text for link</a> " ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Width="100%" />
```

how can i make it?

Comment: put your whole code here so i can get idea.

Comment: ok i edited my question code just added the default text, i need to replace the a innerHTML of the txtALink Text <A> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this updated one: [**http://jsfiddle.net/cfzt9/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfzt9/1/)

my html:

```
<input type='text' id='txtAlinkTitle' value=''/>
<input type='text' style='width:320px' id='txtALink' readonly='true' value="<a href='google.com'>aaa</a>"/>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$('#txtAlinkTitle').keyup(function(){
    var textVal = $(this).val();
    var aa = $('#txtALink').attr('value');
    var bb = aa.substr(0, aa.indexOf('>')+1);
    var cc = aa.substr(aa.indexOf('</a>'));
    $('#txtALink').attr({"value":bb+textVal+cc});
});
```

Comment: hi jai, i dont have real <a> on my form just input with value of "<a href='dsffsdf.com'>replace this</a>

Comment: i dont need to change some real link text , i want to replace the text of an <A> tag inside the input

Comment: updated the fiddle link and the answer. Plz see if this solves.

Comment: thanks its ok for now, i wish to have an answer that do like that: createElement of <a> with the target value then change the innerhtml of the link with the sender value and last thing is to set the new element outHTML in the target value

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong way to give href in textbox text.
You can put anchor tag and set its href value using jquery on textbox change.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAlinkTitle" runat="server" Text="Register Now" onkeyup="changeHref(this)" /><br />
<a id='aTag' href='http://google.com'>my text for link</a> 


funcation changeHref(sender)
{
   $("#aTag").attr('href', sender.val());
}
```

You can also use javascript instead of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put a tag then pass url in function,

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtAlinkTitle" runat="server" Text="Register Now" onkeyup="changeHref(this,url)" /><br />
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtALink" Text="<a href='http://google.com'>my text for link</a> " ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Width="100%" />


funcation changeHref(sender,target,url)
{

   $('#<%=txtALink.ClientID%>').attr('href', '<a href=" + url + " >" + sender.val() + "</a>');
 }
```

or use [Javascript substring method to replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Comment: thats will be my last choice because the input could mess the all embedd link in the textbox,its suppose to be very simple like set new innerHTML as the sender value but its not working for me